# Prove the concavity of the transformation from a concave function to another

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let's say we have $f_1$ and $f_2$, both strictly increasing and strictly concave on $[0,+\infty)$. $f_1(0)=f_2(0)=0$ and the difference $f_1-f_2$ is strictly positive and strictly increasing. That is, $f_1(x)>f_2(x)$ for $x>0$ and $f^\prime_1(x)>f^\prime_2(x)$ for $x>0$.

Can we prove the following intuitive result:

There exist $\phi$, strictly positive, strictly increasing and strictly concave, such that $f_2=\phi(f_1)$. We would have $\phi'<1$.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'd be interested to see a partial result, if this could be applied to 
$$
f_1(x) = ax \quad f_2(x) = bx
$$
for $a>b$.

Comment: I guess $\phi(x)=\frac{b}{a}x$ would do the trick...

Comment: But is this function "strictly concave"?

Comment: Sure not. But I don't think the result holds in this case (if it holds at all).

Comment: In fact, it's clear when we take $f_1(x) = x$ that we must have $\phi(x) = f_2(x)$.  So, it is not possible to generally have a strictly concave $\phi$, nor would we have $\phi' < 1$.

Comment: In this case I agree. But if $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_2$ strictly concave, it works though, with $\phi=f_2$, concave. And we have $\phi'<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refer to concave function, I suppose the definition is [concave upward function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function). Now under the condition in your post, if we suppose $f_2=\phi(f_1)$, then $\phi$ is not only existed, but also unique:
 $f_2=\phi(f_1)\Rightarrow \phi=f_2\circ f_1^{-1},$
 since both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are bijection from $[0,+\infty)$ to $Imf_1, Imf_2$, respectively, therefore they are invertible.

Now we study the property of $\phi$, one can easily check:

(1) $\phi$ is a bijection from $Imf_1$ to $ Imf_2$.

(2) for $y\in Imf_1,$ and $x=f_1^{-1}(y)$,
$$\phi'(y)=f_2'(f_1^{-1}(y))\cdot f_1^{-1}(y)=\frac{f_2'(x)}{ f_1(x)}$$

Since $f^\prime_1(x)>f^\prime_2(x)>0,$ one has $0<\phi'(y)<1.$

(3) The convexity for $\phi$ is uncertain, since $f_1^{-1}$ convex and  $f_2$ concave, and convexity of their composition is uncertain.